# @WebServlet The requested resource is not available

Tags: maven, tomcat, docker, servlets

I have a webapp using both `@Weblistener` and `@WebServlet` Annotations.

When starting the web application the `@Weblistener` annotated class is found and executed. When trying to use one of the servlets, I get a "Resource not available" page.

If I define the servlets additionally in `web.xml`, tomcat complains at startup that the same urlpattern has been used twice, which indicates that `@WebServlet` is being scanned correctly.

The app works fine in Eclipse, but when I build and run it on a tomcat server I get this error.

Please let me know which info you need.

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
  version="3.1" 
  metadata-complete="false"  
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <display-name>MySearchApp</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here's one of the servlet classes

```
@WebServlet(name="SearchServlet", displayName="SearchServlet", urlPatterns={"/search"})
public class Search extends HttpServlet {
```

Here's my maven file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysearchapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>biosearch Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    ......
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>mysearchapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am running the app via Docker. Here's my Dockerfile which is located in the root folder of my project.

```
FROM freedomkk/tomcat-maven:8

ENV BUILD_DIR /tmp/mysearchapp

WORKDIR $BUILD_DIR

COPY . $BUILD_DIR

RUN mvn clean && \
  mvn compile war:war -e && \
  cp target/mysearchapp.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

CMD ["bin/catalina.sh", "run"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: I don't know what the URL is, I created a init method and added loadOnStartup=1 to the Webservlet annotation. In the Init method I printed onto the console --> when starting the container i was able to see the output of the print command

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building the war file on my local machine with Eclipse's embedded Maven runtime. When I tried using an external Maven installation I had the same issue as described above.

The Dockerfile got simpler. I still think that the Maven solution is more elegant.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

COPY mysearchapp.war webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

EXPOSE 8080
```